# Error while adding slick dependency using sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, playframework-2.0, slick-3.0

I'm new in scala world (coming from android world), I have created scala project with play-framework, everything works fine now I need to add database and for that I decided to chose **slick**, but when I'm trying to add dependency like that

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.1.0",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4"
)
```

I'm getting this error log

```
Error:Error while importing SBT project:<br/>...<br/><pre>[info] Resolving com.typesafe#jse_2.10;1.2.3 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#run;0.13.15 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-exceptions;2.6.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#test-interface;1.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.jcraft#jsch;0.1.50 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.6 ...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.14.3 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#compiler-ivy-integration;0.13.15 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#incremental-compiler;0.13.15 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#logic;0.13.15 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe#config;1.3.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#main-settings;0.13.15 ...
[info] Resolving com.lightbend.play#play-file-watch_2.10;1.0.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.6.5 ...
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:ssExtractDependencies' for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:update' for the full output.
[error] (*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.slick#slick_2.12;3.1.0: not found
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.slick#slick_2.12;3.1.0: not found
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed Sep 28, 2017 12:21:57 PM</pre><br/>See complete log in <a href="file:/home/dev-00/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/system/log/sbt.last.log">file:/home/dev-00/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/system/log/sbt.last.log</a>
```

here is my hole sbt build script

```
name := """play-scala-starter-example"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")

scalaVersion := "2.12.2"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.1.0",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4"
)
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "anorm" % "2.5.3"
)

libraryDependencies += guice
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "3.0.0" % Test
libraryDependencies += "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.194"
libraryDependencies += jdbc
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.41"
```

Comment: Try download examples from lightbend web site and try compile them, find out the difference etc. Usually its just issue with versions. it could be issue with scala version as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I find on maven, it seems only few versions of slick are compiled against scala 2.12:

- 3.2.1
- 3.2.0
- 2.1.0

see: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.typesafe.slick%22%20AND%20a%3A%22slick_2.12%22

Either use a more recent version of slick or another scala version (2.11.x).

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your `build.sbt`

```
 resolvers += "typesafe" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
```

Comment: Do you refresh you project after updating your `build.sbt` file ?

Comment: yes, when I run build it says that unresolved dependencies path :com.typesafe.slick:slick_2.12:3.1.0